# Filter a table using the Same criteria for multiple columns?

Tags: vba, excel

i have an Excel Tables with 40 columns.   Columns `F` and `H:R` contains dates.
I want to create with VBA the following Filter.

- If at least one of the date in Columns `F` and `H:R` is Tomorrow Date, Keep those rows and Hide the others

I know how to code multiple criteria for the same field....but not one criteria for several fields...Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column name it ControlColumn and the values of the column are calculated as

```
=COUNTIF(A2:G2, TODAY()+1)
```

see the pic for setup[image]

Then use one filter on **ControlColumn** where value >0 the required range with

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$19").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
```

[image]